# How can I deal with many values in one folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to add random music player on my page. 
And found random music player source. But it has just 2 musics.

If I have many music file over 100 in 'audio' folder, are there some tips dealing with many music files?

[image]

And this is my JavaScirpt code.

```
var lastSong = null;
var selection = null;
var playlist = ["audio/Boy with luv.mp3", "audio/Mikrokosmos.mp3"]; // List of Songs

var player = document.getElementById("audioplayer"); // Get Audio Element
player.autoplay = true;
player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when song ends

function selectRandom() {
  while (selection == lastSong) {
    // Repeat until different song is selected
    selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
  }
  lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
  player.src = playlist[selection]; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song
}

selectRandom(); // Select initial song
player.play(); // Start Song
```

Above code

```
var playlist = ["audio/Boy with luv.mp3", "audio/Mikrokosmos.mp3"];
```

If playlist has many music files, I want to add music file using like for function and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
const fs = require('fs'); // file handling module
const files = fs.readdirSync('.'); // use to read all avaliable file in the current directory
const extname = '.mp3'; // audio file extension
const playlist = files.filter(file => file.endsWith(extname)); // filter out all the files which have `.mp3` extension
```

add these lines above the below line

```
var lastSong = null;
```

and remove your declared `playlist` cause we have now one that comes from this `const playlist = files.filter(file => file.endsWith(extname));`

note: make sure you have you code and mp3 file in same directory.